# Is this sentence, 'try to relieve her by lightening her mood', correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is this sentence, "try to relieve her by lightening her mood", correct, and if so, what is the difference here between **lighten** and **relieve**?

Comment: yes it is correct, lighten her mood means make her kind of cheerful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sentence is correct.

> Relieve: to free from anxiety, fear or pain.
>
> Lighten: to cause to become cheery or glad.

"Lighten" is a synonym of "cheer up". And "relieve" is a synonym of "alleviate".

The difference is pretty clear since relieve does not imply to have a good mood, while lighten does.